# how to find the maclaurin series for the function $f(x)=\sqrt[4]{3+5x^{6}}$?

Tags: analysis

I have found some of the derivatives of the function, but I see no pattern emerging here.

for example, I got the first derivative:
\begin{equation}
f'(x)=\frac{15x^{5}}{2(3+5x^6)}
\end{equation}
and I kept differentiating, but all of the derivatives at $f^n(0)$ are zero, no?

if you can help me, please provide steps
Thanks

Comment: You'll find the sixth derivative is not 0, neither is the twelfth, eighteenth, etc

Comment: Use the binomial theorem. Finding the $n$-th derivative of a function is almost always the worst way to find its Maclaurin series.

Answer (score 1):

Use the generalized binomial theorem

$(3 + 5x^6)^\frac 14 = 3^\frac 14 + \frac 14 3^{-\frac34}(5x^6)+\cdots$

How do you find the rest of the binomial coefficients?

We have a generic term $c_n(3)^{\frac 14 - n}(5x^6)^n$

The next term... $c_{n+1} = c_n(\frac 14-n)\frac {1}{n}$

With what we have above, the next term will be $(\frac 14)(\frac {-3}{4})(\frac 12)(3)^{-\frac 74}(5x^6)^2.$  We can simplify from there, but this gives the idea.

We could also define this using Gamma functions, but I think that this definition is probably adequate.

Answer (score 0):

By the binomial theorem, $f(x)=3^{1/4}(1+5x^6/3)^{1/4}=3^{1/4}\sum_{k\ge0}(5x^6/3)^k\binom{1/4}{k}$, so the Maclaurin series only has powers of $x$ divisible by $6$. The binomial coefficient is$$\frac{1}{k!}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(1/4-j)=\frac{(-1/4)^{k-1}}{k!}\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}(4j-1).$$Or you can write it in terms of the Gamma function as$$\frac{(1/4)!}{k!(1/4-k)!}=\frac{\Gamma(5/4)}{k!\Gamma(5/4-k)!}.$$

Comment: Could you explain how you arrive at this result?

Comment: @Indr Which part?

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to point out that the first derivative is not 
$$\frac{15x^5}{2(3+5x^6)}$$
It's actually
$$\frac{15x^5}{2(3+5x^6)^\frac{3}{4}}$$
That should help you with the next derivatives. Hope that helped!